# Access Relationship Table in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following domains classes:

```
class Posts{
      String Name
      String Country
      static hasMany = [tags:Tags]

        static constraints = {
        }
    }


class Tags{

    String Name
    static belongsTo = Posts
    static hasMany = [posts:Posts]
    static constraints = {
    }
  String toString()
  {
      "${TypeName}"

  }
}
```

Grails creates an another table in the database i.e. Posts_Tags.
My requirement is:

E.g. 1 post has 3 tags.
So, in the Posts_Tags table there are 3 rows.

How can I access the table Posts_Tags directly in my code so that I can manipulate the data or add some more fields to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the join table (`Posts_Tags`) directly, or add properties to it, then you must define it as a separate `PostTag` domain class. You then split your many-many relationship between `Post` and `Tag` into 2 one-to-many relationships (one from `Post` to `PostTag` and one from `Tag` to `PostTag`).

Here's a [comprehensive example](http://www.grails.org/Many-to-Many+Mapping+without+Hibernate+XML) of how to perform the mapping and add properties to the join table - in this example `Membership` is the join table.

Comment: The comprehensive example link says 'You are not authorized' even after registering

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal groovy sql API. For an example of how to get a groovy SQL object and execute sql queries see [this](http://bradrhoads.blogspot.com/2010/02/sqldatabase-views-in-grails-stack.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the 2nd part of his question about how to add extra fields to the join table

Comment: Yes it does, if you have a groovy SQL object you can use alter table statements, insert, etc.