# Grails accessing relationship tables

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

I have one many-to-many relationship in my app which looks like this: class

```
App {
    String type
    String name

    static hasMany = [users: User]
}

class User {
    String email
    String regid

    static belongsTo = App
    static hasMany = [apps:App]

}
```

Now i want to access all Users of an app, by having its id. I prefer using plain SQL as It is working way faster and I database will have ~one million records. So i need a way to access all users of an app where app id in (array of given apps).

What I am trying is doing something like this:

```
def result = sql.eachRow('SELECT App_Users from App where id in(?)' [id:params.app_checkbox])
```

But this throws me exception as column App_users is not available.

I am trying to do this for 4-5 hours and bearing in mind I am not a web developer, it is already driving me crazy, so could you guys  give me advice, how to access members of many-to-many relationship with sql?

Comment: Possible duplicated:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238807/many-to-many-link-tables-in-grails-gorm-hibernate

and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477903/access-relationship-table-in-grails

Answer (score 1):

At last i managed to achieve it with simple criteria:

```
 def results = App.createCriteria().list() {
                createAlias('users', 'user')
                'in'("id", goodIds)
                projections {
                    count('users')
                }
            }
```